# Restart does not shutdown first on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, login, shutdown, bios

I installed Debian Squeeze from the live DVD. Going to `System`->`Shutdown`->`Restart` does not shutdown the computer in the usual way where the BIOS screen is seen before login. Instead it simply restarts without going through shutdown and BIOS. Why is that so? Can we configure restart behaviour to switch between these two ways of restarting? I have not experienced this on other Linux distributions or Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a feature of [`kexec`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec).  If you don't like it, try `coldreboot` (from `kexec-tools`) or set `LOAD_KEXEC=false` in `/etc/default/kexec` ([as mentioned here](http://wiki.debian.org/ALSA)).
You could proably also just remove [the package`kexec-tools`](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=kexec-tools)